# InvokeProcess custom activity does not invoke

Tags: custom-activity

I'm doing my first steps on Customizing the TFS builds. I created an InvokeProcess that calls a batch file. I see in the log that the batch file is called, but I do not see that the batch file is executed. In the FileName I put the located and the name of the file (for example "C:\myBatch.bat".
Just to see it working, I called in the file name also "Notepad.exe" and also it did not work.
What can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify the WorkingDirectory property for the Invoke Process Activity, If you have file path as "C:\myBatch.bat" then set WorkingDirectory as "c:\"

Also, you can enable the logging for Invoke Process Activity. Check here: 
https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/archive/2010/02/23/logging-results-from-invokeprocess-in-a-vs2010-team-build.aspx

Comment: Hi...It does not help to me...I set in the WorkingDIrectory for example "C:\" and in the file "C:\MyBatch.bat" without any result.

Comment: @Maslow Here's the working link: https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2010/02/23/logging-results-from-invokeprocess-in-a-vs2010-team-build.aspx